# GDM3 Crashes system when external monitor connected with Wayland

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, lightdm, gdm

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 today and would like to use it with my external monitor.
However, I have discovered that connecting the monitor before startup made the system hang at the purple login screen.
If I connected it after logging on, the whole system would crash.

I read an article saying that installing lightdm might fix the issue, and I was skeptical at first but tried it.
After having a successful startup with my external monitor, I attempted to disable Wayland in GDM3 for login, and it worked.

I am using the recommended drivers from "Additional Drivers"
PRIME Profile set to high-performance

I am quite new to Linux, so I'm sorry if I don't give enough info.

System info: https://pastebin.com/X8Ys4K09

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Bugs are off topic here. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug?r=SearchResults&s=3|0.0000)

Comment: Also make sure the UEFI is updated and that you installed the OS in UEFI mode.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I am already in UEFI, and have installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: @user68186 I am not trying to report a bug, I am trying to get help.